# Tailwind Dark Mode - always loads OS preference and ignores dark class

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, tailwind-css, darkmode

I've trying to implement a dark mode toggle in a static Nuxt app and Tailwind is ignoring the presence of the `dark` class and is loading the OS preference.

My toggle works fine and add/removes the `dark` class from the `<html>` element and reads/writes to `localStorage` on page load or when changed.

I've set `darkMode: "class"` in the tailwind config but it doesn't appear to work, either on page load when the cookie indicates light mode or when toggled via my switch :(
I'm at a loss as how to fix this and would appreciate any pointers.

```
tailwind.config.ts

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "~/components/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "~/layouts/**/*.{js,vue}",
    "~/pages/**/*.{js,vue}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  darkMode: "class",
};
```

Here's a [screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE6aE.png) showing the `light` mode active (i.e. no class applied to `<html>`) and `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` applied. The same applies vice-versa (i.e. OS set to light mode won't load dakr mode).

Comment: I did indeed solve it, but I probably won't be able sit down at my PC and provide a solution until tomorrow.

Comment: no problem, I fixed it too, even though I'm not sure how :D as I did a lot of changes and attempts

Comment: Anyway you can  point me in the right direction? I changed darkMode to class in tailwind.config.js and everything